# Hosking test vs Granger Causality for VAR - to use or not to use?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, vector-autoregression, cross-correlation, granger-causality

Let's say that we have 2 stationary time series: X and Y. Granger's causality test outputs **no granger causality** between them, however Hosking cross-correlation test proves **there is a relationship between these two series**. Which one of them should be a stronger indication to use or not to use VAR model? Does Granger Causality test take into consideration also the possibility of existance a VARMA process?